# Error: iterator should return strings, not _io.TextIOWrapper (did you open the file in text mode?)

Tags: python, csv

I'm starting with python 3.6.1, I want to read a csv document using this code:

```
f = open ("mon_fichier.csv"),"r"

import csv

lecteur = csv.DictReader(f,delimiter=";")

for ligne in lecteur :
    print (ligne)

f.close()
```

I'm getting this error message

```
Error: iterator should return strings, not _io.TextIOWrapper (did you open the file in text mode?)
```

Do you know why?

Comment: Questions should be in English on StackOverflow!

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with your syntax:

```
f = open ("mon_fichier.csv"),"r"
```

Means that `type(f) == tuple`, i.e. it is a 2-tuple with a file-handle and a `"r"` string. You meant:

```
f = open("mon_fichier.csv", "r")
```

Or, since `"r"` is the default mode, you could just do:

```
f = open("mon_fichier.csv")
```

And really, it is best-practice to use a context manager, so you should do:

```
import csv

with open("mon_fichier.csv") as f:
    lecteur = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=";")
    for ligne in lecteur :
        print(ligne)
```